# how to grep certain string which matches certain value

Tags: bash, unix, tcl

I have file abc.sh which contains below data -

```
a_a_1 was unsuccessful
a_a_5 was completed
a_a_2 was unsuccessful
a_a_4 was unsuccessful
a_a_9 was unsuccessful
```

now, I have a variable `abc` which contains value `2,1,9` ..i.e `abc=2,1,9`
now want to print only those lines from file which matches value `2,1,9` and above string.
output should be like-

```
a_a_2 was unsuccessful
a_a_1 was unsuccessful
a_a_9 was unsuccessful
```

How to achieve above output?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable need to be:

- `abc="2\|1\|9"` for `grep $abc abc.sh`
- `a=2 b=1 c=9` for `grep "[$a]\|[$b]\|[$c]" abc.sh`

Well as your question, if you want for `abc=2,1,9` , you can just change the `,` as `\|` using `sed` when executing `grep` like this:

```
grep $(echo $abc | sed "s/,/\\\|/g") abc.sh
```

**ps: English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar mistakes :)*

Comment: Or use `grep '[129]'` or `grep -E '1|2|9'` instead of a non-standard extension to BREs. But they'll all match `a_a_25`...

Comment: Hi...but i have to match unsuccessful string also not only the number

Comment: Edited. I just noticed the mistakes in the first edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged `tcl`...

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc main {abc} {
    set abc [string map {, |} $abc]
    set re [string cat {^a_a_(?:} $abc {)\M}]
    while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
        if {[regexp $re $line]} {
            puts $line
        }
    }
}
main [lindex $argv 0]
```

Example usage:

```sh
$ ./findit.tcl 2,1,9 < abc.sh
```

Basically, it converts the CSV `2,1,9` into pipe delimited `2|1|9` and uses that as part of a bigger regular expression, and prints lines read from standard input that match it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you also seem to be interested in a bash solution (you already got one for Tcl):

```
grep -E "_(${abc//,/|}) " abc.sh
```

The idea here is to translate the `2,1,9` into the regexp pattern `2|1|9`. An alternative, similar in spirit, would be

```
grep "_[${abc//,/}] " abc.sh
```

which produces the pattern `[219]`.

Comment: First one should be `"_(${abc//,/|}) " to avoid unexpected matches.

Comment: @Shawn : As far I can see, this exactly what I have written. Where is the difference?

Comment: `_2|1|9<space>` will match anything with a 1 in it and things like `_25` or `59<space>`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the parenthesis! Now I see it.